# Not able to open ubuntu software center and update manager

Tags: installation

A few days back I have installed Google chrome in my Ubuntu but I shutdown my PC before the installation was completed. Now I am getting an error

```
E:The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'
```

while opening them. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to remove it

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq google-chrome-stable
```

then re install it again.